# Can you explain what this programs are doing?

Tags: c++

So I have to do trace tables for this but I don't understand everything from the code such as a==b; c-=--d; b+=a%10

```
  int a=3,b=4, c=5,d=6;
if(a==b)c++;else c--;
while(d>2){
    c-=--d; b-=a;
}
    int a=3,b=0, c=7,d=5;
if(a=b)d++;else c--;
while(d>2){
    c+=a;a+=--d;
}

    int a=3,b=11, c=15,d=5;
if(a>b)d--;else c--;
for(;d>3;c/=a){
    b=--d;
}

    int a=31,b=14, c=95,d=56;
if(a<b)d++;else c--;
while(d>53){
    b+=a%10;d--; a/=10;
}
```

Comment: `c-=--d` looks like someone has run out of white spaces ;) `c -= --d`

Comment: i can give you the values of a b c and d but that would be doing your homework

a==b is asking for a comparison

Comment: If you're supposed to trace through this program but you don't understand operators… well, I suspect you probably understand them but are confused because they're being combined in an almost unnatural manner. Just take your time, break things up and think through it.

Comment: This code is an abomination.

Comment: Try using this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence. Looks like your professor is trying to teach you what not to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
c -= --d;
```

mean

```
c = c - (--d);
```

The same goes for

```
b += a%10
```

which mean

```
b = b + (a%10)
```

You can do the same with *, / and % operator

--d mean that d is decreased before the instruction get executed, ++d would mean d will be increased before the instruction got executed

```
if(a==b)c++;else c--;
```

is the same as the more readable

```
if (a==b)
{
    c = c + 1;
}
else
{
    c = c - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a=3,b=4, c=5,d=6;
if(a==b) c++;
else c--;
while(d>2){
    c-=--d; b-=a;
}
```

The `==` operator means comparasion if a and b are the same. In this case a and b are different, so it goes to the else and decrements the c variable for 1.

The -- after c means that the value is decreased before the instruction gets executed.

So, that means c will become 4.

While `d > 2`, means it will loop as long as `d > 2`.

`c -= --d; b-=a;`

That means:

`c = c - --d`

`b = b - a`

So, that means the value of d will decrease by 1 each time the loop is executed and will keep looping until it's >2.

```
int a=3,b=0, c=7,d=5;
if(a=b)d++;
else c--;
while(d>2){
    c+=a;a+=--d;
}
```

The `=` operator means to assign a value, so when it executed `a=b`, it will assign the value of `b` to `a` but since it's `0`, which means `false` it will go to else and decrease the value of c by 1.

So c will become 6.

The while loop is similar to the first one.

```
int a=3,b=11, c=15,d=5;
if(a>b)d--;else c--;
for(;d>3;c/=a){
    b=--d;
}
```

This one is quite simple if-statement. It checks whether a is bigger than b. If so, it executes d--, else c--.

As for the for-loop, it goes until `d > 3` and it executes `c /= a` each time as well.

`c /= a` also can be written as `c = c / a`.

```
int a=31,b=14, c=95,d=56;
if(a<b)d++;else c--;
while(d>53){
    b+=a%10;d--; a/=10;
}
```

The last one if statement is simple as well and similar to the above one.

The while loop will be executed until `d > 53`.

The command inside `b+=a%10;d--; a/=10;` can be also written as:

`b = b + a % 10`

`d--`

`a = a / 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
a==b
```

This is an important Boolean condition that checks whether a is equal to b and returns true if it is and returns false if it is not. This can be changed (casted) to an `int` of value 1 or 0.

```
c-=--d;
```

I wouldn't prefer writing such code.

```
However c -= k statement is equivalent to c = c-k
and --d; is same as decrement d by 1.
```

The code does these two things in one statement. But order is important. Since -- comes before d, first this decrement is evaluated and then the -= operator is considered.

Similarly for +=

I would suggest looking up a good C++ learning resource such as www.cplusplus.com or www.learncpp.com